# Can i delete default MongoDB Index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

I have one collection for  which I don't need any index. I just store user search term and date, so my collection is really simple.

```
class UserSearch {

public string Term {get; set;}
pulic DateTime Date {get;set;}

}
```

When I store one UserSearch item, my collection have _id and default index on it.

From my knowledge, those "_id" fields will be indexed in ram, so I don't want to spend ram memory for collection which I just store and I'm calculating something every 12 hours.

I try to delete it, but I can't.

```
   var indexes = UserSearch(true).GetIndexes();

   //delete UserSearch Default Index
   if(UserSearch(true).IndexExistsByName("_id_"))
   {
     UserSearch(true).DropIndexByName("_id_");
   }
```

Any suggestion/solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you can't delete it.

From the [MongoDB documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/Indexes.html#Indexes-The%5CidIndex), emphasis mine;

> The _id Index
>
> For all collections except capped collections, an index is
>   automatically created for the _id field. This index is special and
>   ***cannot be deleted***. The _id index enforces uniqueness for its keys
>   (except for some situations with sharding).

Answer (score 5):

You can't delete the `_id` index once created. However you can create a collection without `_id` indexes by setting the `autoIndexId` option to `false` using [**`db.createCollection`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection) but without `_id` you can't replicate your collection.

Comment: Actually you don't need _id for replication or sharding. You can set any other index or compound index.

Comment: @AdrianLopez Kindly take note of the Warning: `IMPORTANT

For replica sets, do not set autoIndexId to false.` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection

Comment: @sstyvane I am aware of that, except that AdrianLopez is contradicting you so I am responding to him accordingly.

Comment: `Deprecated since version 3.2`: The autoIndexId option will be removed in version 3.4. By MongoDb docs